# On button click, Read text from 'p' html tag & open in new window browser tab

Tags: cypress

I am new in cypress testing. On button click read 'p' html tag content text which is url & open url into different browser tab.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress can't handle multiple browser tabs. If you want to test the hyperlink for the `p` element you could do two things:
1. Check what the URL is (and that is probably not the `p` element but an `a href` element. You could check that via:

```js
cy.get('a')
  .should('have.attr', 'href', 'URL_WHICH_IT_SHOULD_CONTAIN')
```

2. Click the element to see if the URL is correct:

```js
cy.get('p')
  .click()
cy.url()
  .should('contain', 'URL_WHICH_IT_SHOULD_CONTAIN')
```

Comment: On button click, read text content of 'p' tag open into new window tab

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with that comment

Comment: Can you show me your code? I can't answer this question without your code.